# mpdf can not be installed in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, composer-php, mpdf

i am using laravel 9 and my PhP version is 8.0.2, and I am trying to install Mpdf package, so I write the following command

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

but I get this error
Problem 1

```
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.1.0, ..., v8.1.2] require psr/log ^1.0 || ^2.0 -> found psr/log[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.4, 2.0.0] but the package is fixed to 3.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires mpdf/mpdf ^8.1 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.1.0, v8.1.1, v8.1.2].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I have tried to delete the vendor and composer.lock and use composer update and it does work

Comment: try this: 

composer require mpdf/mpdf -w

Answer (score 2):

mPDF is not compatible with `psr/log` 3.x because of support of older PHP versions (which do not have return type hints).
Previously installed Laravel is forcing `psr/log` library to version 3.x.

You can use flag `--with-all-dependencies` along with `composer require mpdf/mpdf` to downgrade the dependency automatically.

Alternatively, downgrade the `psr/log` library to 2.x - just add or change to `"psr/log": "^2.0"` line in your composer.json file and run `composer update`. This will resolve the issue.

Or you can first require mPDF and then Laravel, that should also work. Or require them both in one command.

Comment: there is no psr/log line in composer.json :(

Comment: then add it. or use flag --with-all-dependencies, as updated in the answer

Comment: it works with using the command composer require psr/log ^2.0. thank you guys for your help

Comment: requiring psr/log *may* solve the first-hand issue here, however I'd not suggest it as the preferable solution as it is a transitive dependency but requiring it in the root package makes it a liar. Please comment if/why `--with-all-dependencies`  was not an option @ShadyHesham