# laravel mpdf (carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf) package is not working in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, mpdf

i am using mpdf laravel (carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf) package but when I run the pdf i get the following error

```
Declaration of Mpdf\Mpdf::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger) must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface::setLogger(Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger): void
```

I have tried to change psr/log to "^1.1 || ^2.0" in composer.lock because when I install the package mpdf it requires it. but it does not work and here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "anhskohbo/no-captcha": "^3.4",
        "carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf": "^2.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.14.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "mcamara/laravel-localization": "^1.7",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.11",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helper.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
      }
```

Comment: Sounds like you shoud report this an an error to the issue tracker of the package causing the problem

Comment: https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf/issues/103 - there's already an issue about that.

Answer (score 0):

It is the fault of the wrapper library that it lets you install incompatible versions of dependencies. As Nico Haase mentions in a comment above, the issue has already been mitigated in the library.

On a side note, you never alter the composer.lock file manually. Changes made will be overwritten with the next `composer install` call. You need to force `psr/log` to version 2.x in your composer.json file, [as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580566/819007) in your previous question.

Answer (score -1):

after install package .

then go to your composer.json

"require": {

```
     "psr/log": "2.0"  //add there psr/log 2.0
```

}

then run composer update. thenn booo its's done

or follow this link Instruction

https://arif98741.medium.com/generate-bangla-text-content-in-pdf-using-laravel-1f786b4d1362

Comment: What do you mean by "add there"?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What **exactly** should be added where, and why?

Comment: Please share more details. How is your answer different from the one by Finwe posted some months ago?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).